# How to change scene in unity based on the value from inputfield

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I want to open a scene in unity based on the value typed in input field.

For example:

if the user inputs 4, scene name numbers will be loaded
if the user inputs 5, scene name numbers1 will be loaded

Answer (score 0):

You have to call SceneManager.LoadScene, here is the reference: https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/SceneManagement.SceneManager.LoadScene.html

In order for something like this to work you'll need to read input. This could be done through an Input Field like this: https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/UI.InputField-text.html

Or maybe a dropdown: https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/script-Dropdown.html

Then set up a button that'll parse the input and call the function SceneManager.LoadScene.

Answer (score 0):

To get the changed text event you can use the OnValueChange property on the textfield https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/script-InputField.html

To load a scene use the SceneManager.LoadScene("SceneName") method https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/SceneManagement.SceneManager.LoadScene.html

Answer (score 0):

You can do it this way by referencing the InputField and calling the 
 `ChangeSceneBasedOnInputField()` from a button event

```
public UnityEngine.UI.InputField sceneInputField; //Refence to your inputField

public void ChangeSceneBasedOnInputField() //Code that needs to be called
 {
      UnityEngine.SceneManagement.SceneManager.LoadScene(sceneInputField.text);  
     //This way you can type either the index of the scene or it's name
     //Will throw an error if it can`t find the scene
}
```